# MySQL Query not returning specific search parameters via php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php driven page that allows me to enter search parameters. One of these numbers is an ID that consists of several digits. When I search for one with these specific digits it returns all results.

I have done the exact same statement in phpmyadmin and the SQL terminal and it returns just the item I searched for. So I suppose the problem lies with the PHP I am using to submit the search query based on the html form.

The drop down with the status options works fine - any of the fields that requires input do not.

Also I am sure the fields are submitting to the database because I can view them and complete SQL statements with them in phpadmin

**EDIT** echo result when NumericIdentider is entered and default status of all is selected: **Select * From Table Where Closed != ' '**

```
<?php
  if($_REQUEST['Search']) {
    $sql = "SELECT";

    if(strlen($_REQUEST['NumericIdentifier']) > 0) {
      $sql .= " * FROM Table Where NumericIdentifier = ".$_REQUEST['NumericIdentifier'];
    }

    if(strlen($_REQUEST['BeginDate']) > 0) {
      $sql .= " * From Table Where TDate >= {$_REQUEST['BeginDate']}";
    }

    if(strlen($_REQUEST['EndDate']) > 0) {
      $sql .= " * From Table Where TDate <= {$_REQUEST['EndDate']}";
    }

    if($_REQUEST['Status'] == 'Shipped') {
      $sql .= "* From Table Where Closed = 'true' ";
    }

    if($_REQUEST['AreaCode'] >  0) {
      $sql .= " * From Table Where AreaCode = {$_REQUEST['AreaCode']}";
    }

    if($_REQUEST['Status'] == 'Recieved') {
      $sql .= " * From Table Where Closed != 'true'";
    }

    if($_REQUEST['Status'] == 'All') {
      $sql = "Select * From Table Where Closed != '\0'";
    }
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tickets";
  }

  $res =  mysql_query($sql, $conn1);
  while($a = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<a href='ticket.php?id=".$a['id']."'>".trim($a['id'])."</a>&nbsp;</td> \n <td> ".$a['Name']."</td> \n <td>".date("m/d/Y", strtotime($a['TicketDate']))."</td> \n <td>".$a['Issue']."</td> \n <td>".Showstatus($a['Closed'])." </td></tr>";
  } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. how about printing $sql and looking at the result (also known as "debugging") before posting this here? 2. more than one of those requests can be true at the same time, so you probably get a really strange query 3.  do you really need all columns?

Comment: Try echoing $sql after all you if statements. I am sure the sql being generated is not the one you want. Try executing that in phpmyadmin then.

Comment: I am aware about the combined state and how it will come out incorrect. The fact is even by themselves it does not submit correctly.

Comment: Ok so my problem is the multiple states. Specifically the All case because it defaults to that.

Comment: so you need to fix the frontend ;) (and the backend)

Comment: When I take out the "All" status it works. So I need to figure out how to make a combine condition if more than one search paramter is chosen

Comment: How can I make a conditional inclusion of multiple search parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Yeesh, your SQL will never work. Let's say the user enters both a BeginDate and and EndDate, your query will be

```
SELECT
 * From Table Where TDate >= {$_REQUEST['BeginDate']}
 * From Table Where TDate <= {$_REQUEST['EndDate']}
```

Even if the dates were entered properly in MySQL form (YYYY-MM-DD), it will still come out as

```
SELECT
 * FROM Table Where TDate >= 01/01/2011
 * FROM Table Where TDate <= 31/12/2011
```

Notice there's no quotes around the dates. MySQL will see those "dates" as being numbers, being divided, so you're saying `TDate >= 0.0004972...` and `TDate <= 0.001284...`

On top of that, saying `* from table` twice is also illegal syntax.

Your code is very obviously NOT checking for error states. At absolute bare minimum you should have:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

which will tell you exactly what's wrong with the query you've constructed.

And, worst of all, as others have said, you're completely open and vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, but I'm not going to go into that... your query is so hopeless broken already that an injection attack is the least of your worries.